# Is there a better way to express this fluent registration in Windsor?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Basically I would like a way to express: Find all classes with base class `AbstractDataService<>` and resolve them by their interface and not by their base class.
I currently have this and it works but it isn't very elegant:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.Pick()
   .FromAssembly(typeof(AbstractDataService<>).Assembly)
   .If(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs(typeof(AbstractDataService<>)))
   .WithService.FirstInterface());
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Looks good to me... why do you say it's not elegant?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: I am missing something like HasBaseOf(typeof(AbstractDataService<>)).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use .BasedOn(...)?

Comment: But BasedOn for some reason returns all of the types in my namespace if I ommit .If(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs(typeof(AbstractDataService<>))).

Answer (score 0):

You can create intermediate variables.  But...I'm not really sure what the real problem is.  Complex things look complex.  This is reality.

Comment: But even complex things can be simplified through helpers I don't know of.